# Convert NSData to NSArray error

Tags: ios, swift2

I use iCloudDocumentSync library to store/retrieve files in iCloud (iCloud Container). I have NSArray of objects and I convert this array to NSData:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(foundationArray)
```

and store file to iCloud. All works fine.

When i retrieved this file, and try convert NSData to NSArray I have error:

```
iCloud.sharedCloud().retrieveCloudDocumentWithName(backupName, completion: { (document, data, error) -> Void in

                if error == nil {
                    print(document.fileURL)
//                    let addressBook = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(document.fileURL.URLString)
                    let addressBook = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
                    print(addressBook)
                    progressHUD.hide(true)
                }
            })
```

Eror:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'AutocodingException', reason: 'Expected 'url' to be a NSURL, but was actually a __NSCFString'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185cc822c 0x19799c0e4 0x185cc816c 0x1003354f0 0x1003355c8 0x186b40d98 0x186b47fd0 0x186ad67d8 0x186b40d98 0x186b401b4 0x186b43154 0x186b42fec 0x10033540c 0x1003355c8 0x186b40d98 0x186b47fd0 0x186ad67d8 0x186b40d98 0x186b401b4 0x186b3f3dc 0x1000bdfc8 0x1000bcdf4 0x10076a0d0 0x101878fd4 0x101878f94 0x10187dc28 0x185c7f544 0x185c7d5ec 0x185ba8f74 0x18f6036fc 0x18a7aad94 0x1000cccd0 0x198046a08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: there is no `url` variable, is the error from this part of code?

Comment: and show code, not screenshots of code.

Comment: @aaisataev Yes. Error on this part code

Comment: @aaisataev troubles was with AutoCoding library. And Swift show wrong Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your url into NSURL, you are passing to argument type that accept NSURL.

```
let UrlToUse = NSURL(string: url)
```